# What is the fastest, smallest, easiest way to use bitTorrent on an iPad 2?

Tags: ipad, torrent

Safari won't let me download [utorrent](http://www.utorrent.com/downloads/complete?os=mac&track=stable), which I use and love on my MacBook pro. Any similar programs that work on an iPad without jail breaking the device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a Mac, the simplest solution might be to install [Transmission](http://www.transmissionbt.com/) on your Mac, use its web interface (which looks great on iOS), and let the torrents download on your Mac.

From iOS, you can control almost everything, and add torrents by pasting in URLs, since Mobile Safari doesn't let you do file uploads. It's not exactly what you asked for, but if you don't absolutely need the download to be happening on your iPad, this is much simpler.

If you really need the files to end up on your iPad though, you could try something like [this](http://www.redmondpie.com/how-to-download-torrents-on-iphone-ipad-without-jailbreaking-tutorial/).

Comment: Thanks for the info, but Torrific isn't exactly fast and easy, and yes, by "use" BitTorrent on my iPad, I mean download media on my iPad.

Comment: Without Jailbreaking, you *will never* download media directly onto your iPad. Not via Torrents anyways. Period. BitTorrent apps will not be allowed into the App Store. There's too much legal grey areas, plus the fact that using a torrent app on your iPad would burn through your battery in a heartbeat.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an iPad app where you can download torrent as there is no way to store and open the file, plus, not that Apple's going to let a bittorrent app on the iPad anyways.